# Setting default hash algorithm for signing certificate programatically

Tags: windows, security, outlook, cryptography, truststore

[Screenshot of Outlook Trust Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRNRp.jpg)

Hi,

I am using Cryptography API to import my certificate to the Trust Store. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx)

I am using the following steps:
1. Opening the trust store
2. Create a certificate context
3. Adding the certificate to the certificate context
4. Set friendly name using certificate context property
5. Setting CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO property where I am setting my custom cryptographic service provider with ProvType as PROV_RSA_FULL

The hash algorithm of my certificate is SHA-1. However, when we import it to the trust store using the crypto API, the default Hash Algorithm is being shown as SHA 512 (as shown in the image). What property do I need to set in the cert context so that I can set the default Hash Algorithm of the certificate in the Trust Store, same as what I have in the certificate?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't comparing the hash method of the signature with the one used to calculate the fingerprint over the certificate? You really don't want to use SHA-1 for the signature generation method anyway.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I am not comparing hash method of the signature with the one used to calculate fingerprint. The problem is that we are using our custom implementation to upload the certificates to trust center. However, the certificates uploaded by our implementation takes the highest hash algorithm available, by default. For eg, If the highest hash algo available in my registry is SHA 256, the certificate is taking the value SHA-256.
We have to use SHA-1 signature generation method because of client's requirement :)